Tangent at a point is normal at other point.find the other point
The normal to the curve 5x⁵ - 10x³ + x + 2y + 6 = 0 at the point P(0, -3) is tangent to the curve at some other point(s). Find those point(s)?
So I had two approaches
First is I equate the slope of normal at (0,3) to the slope of tangent to the equation i.e
$$\frac{-1}{\frac{dy}{dx}} at (0,-3)=\frac{dy}{dx }$$
But the answer is coming out to be wrong
Instead when I write the equation of line for normal then substitute y with the expression of x then get values of x I get the correct answer
Maybe did a calculation mistake or am I missing something?

I guess I got the point the line of normal is tangent to the curve again but in first method I am just equating the slopes but they could be different lines .

is the equation of the curve $5x^5 - 10x^3 + x + 2y + 6 = 0$

HINTS:
We have
$$-2y=5x^5-10x^3+x+6 $$
The graph passes through$(0,-3 )$
With respect to $y=-3$ it is an odd function. Differentiate w.r.t. x
$$-2 y'= 25 x^4-30 x^2 +1$$
which is an even function. At $x=0,$ slope
$$y'=\frac{-1}{2}$$
To find $x$ when slope at other points has negative reciprocal
$$ y'=+2$$
$$25x^4-30x^2+1=-4,~\text{  factoring  } ~5(x^2-1)(5x^2-1)=0$$
$$x=\pm 1,\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 5};$$
Verify that at each of the four abscissas the slope is always
$$y'=2.$$
